# Javascript onclick does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

First and foremost, I know a little more than nothing about Javascript, so please excuse me if this is an ultra novice question.

I am trying to get this button to trigger:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();">Toggle</button>
```

My code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction();">Toggle</button>
<p id="toggle">x<p>
```

Works fine on desktop and desktop responsive, but I can't get it to work on any actual mobile device.

I think the answer, through my googling, might be "add touch events", but I am not certain. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `"vclick"` with Jquery(for example)

Example:

```
$( document ).on( "vclick", "p", function() {
  $( this ).append( "<span style='color:#108040;'> vclick fired... </span>" );
  });
```

See the docs: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

With pure JS , you can try to use the `onmousedown`. It works perfectly. I tested it on mobile just now. Take a look:

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("toggle");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">sdfsdfsd</div>
<button onmousedown="myFunction();">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful to me as a novice. I don't understand how and where to implement this.

Comment: You never worked with Jquery? You want it to work with pure JS?

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it out

Comment: Thank you for doing that for me. Unfortunately it is still not working on mobile. It works on "mobile" (and responsive mode) in developer tools in Chrome, but not on my actual mobile device on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('Click');
});

btn.addEventListener('tap', () => {
  alert('Mobile click / Tap');
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Hope this helps, have a nice day!

Comment: Check my updated answer, worked on iPhone 6S+ iOS 12!

Comment: Evaluation Unit, please check my bin, i rewrited your code to good variant. https://jsbin.com/donocus/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Updated answer doesn't work on mobile or desktop for me. "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: I checked your bin. Thank you for doing that for me! However it doesn't implement into my page properly, a la the error I get above still happens.